# getting wrong ans in output while using getche()

Tags: c++

Here is my code

```
#include<iostream>//Per processor directive
#include<conio.h>                      //For getche()
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int no,no2,no3,no4;
   cout<<"Enter no\n";
   no=getche();
   cout<<"+";
   no2=getche();
   no3=no+no2;
   cout<<"\nAns "<<no3;


   return 0;


}
 //output
```

my output is this

```
Enter no
5+5
Ans is 106
```

why i am getting 106 instead of 10
any help will be appreciated

Comment: You have to substract 96 twice...

Comment: why should i subtract 96 twice

Comment: Because (no-96) + (no2-96)

Comment: The year 1995 called. It wants it's `conio.h` back.

Comment: But ASCII `0` is decimal 48, so why subtract 96 twice?

Comment: *"ASCII 0 is decimal 48"* Yes, my bad

Comment: actually i required to subtract 96 only once to get the answer

Comment: thanks you people have given me idea ,because my input isn't taken as integer but its ASCII Value which is 53 for 5 which makes 5+5=53+53

Answer (score 0):

1. It seems that `getche()` already subtracts 48 from your input. Two blank spaces produce the result -112, which is `((32 - 48) - 48) + ((32 - 48) - 48)`, so you're always subtracting 96 too much.
2. You don't need `getche()`, your code doesn't even compile without warnings in Visual C++ 2013, and since you're using `iostream` and `std::cout` anyway, why don't you continue with `std::cin`?

**Edit**: 
With `_getche()` the code works correctly. I have no idea why. Please use something like `std::cin` instead, `getche()` is outdated.

```
#include <iostream>

int main( )
{
    int Input_1;
    int Input_2;
    int Result;
    std::cout << "Your addition: \n";
    std::cin >> Input_1;

    std::cout << "+ \n";
    std::cin >> Input_2;

    Result = Input_1 + Input_2;
    std::cout << "\n" << "Result: " << Result;

    //Keep the window open
    getchar( );
    getchar( );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: actually the + sign which should  come in the line of input is disturbed by this

Answer (score 0):

getche() is used to accept a character as  input.if you enter 5 then ASCII value of "5" is 53, so answer is 106.